# How do I test ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actionmailer

I am using ActionMailer for the first time. It becomes a chore having to go into the development.log to and check if they are going, and I would like to write an automated test.  What is the best/most practical solution for testing ActionMailer emails on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [email-spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) gem. It's really good and you can test a lot of stuff with it.